# Safari will not load css file from external server

Tags: css, safari, stylesheet, cross-site

One of the sites I am developing is loading an external stylesheet:

```
@import url(http://www.othersite.com/stylesheet.css);
```

This works in every single browser properly, except for Safari. Safari does not even try to load it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Could it have to do with this old bug: http://www.thinkoomph.com/thinking/2011-04/odd-css-bug-in-webkit-and-safari-4/ ?

> The solution is simple. My @import directive was surrounded by other
>   CSS instructions. Whereas IE tolerates this, the actual W3C spec
>   declares that @import directives should appear before any other CSS
>   instructions, and Firefox honors this restriction. Thus, my @import
>   directive was being ignored. I moved it to the top of the file and
>   everything started working.

and

> At most one @charset rule may appear in an external style sheet — it
>   must not appear in an embedded style sheet — and it must appear at the
>   very start of the document, not preceded by any characters.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case in my instance, as all the other @import statement before this one are treated fine, recognized and loaded. Perhaps because this is the last entry in my master stylesheet file that may have caused an issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.othersite.com/stylesheet.css" />
```

I stumbled upon the solution while reading an article that details the pros and cons of using @import vs.  tag. I tried using a  tag instead of @import, and for whatever reason this solved my issue. Safari will now load the stylesheet. If anyone has any insight into why this works please comment :)

Comment: I was going to suggest this as a solution in comments above and ask you why you decided to use `@import` rather than the more common `link` tag.

Comment: The reason with sticking with @import instead of link, is because link will not properly cascade as far as I am aware. Does that make sense?